# When does the PostgreSQL 12 CTE materialized option provide an optimization advantage?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-12

EDIT: I have **moved** this question over to [`dba.stackexchange`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/262178/when-does-the-postgresql-12-cte-materialized-option-provide-an-optimization-adva) as I have received advice that that community can better address my question.

I have been reading about PostgreSQL's new CTE feature - the MATERIALIZED or NOT MATERIALIZED keyword - which can offer additional optimization opportunities under certain circumstances, provided that it is safe to do so. A comment on this PostgreSQL update [here](https://www.depesz.com/2019/02/19/waiting-for-postgresql-12-allow-user-control-of-cte-materialization-and-change-the-default-behavior/) says:

> ... the user can force the old behavior [LESS OPTIMIZED] by
>   specifying MATERIALIZED; this would mainly be useful when the query
>   had deliberately been employing WITH as an optimization fence to
>   prevent a poor choice of plan.

I have been wondering, given that there is a situation where it is safe to use the CTE optimization (NOT MATERIALIZED keyword), under which circumstances can the less optimized "MATERIALIZED" keyword "prevent a poor choice of plan" as the quote says or provide an even better plan?

Answer (score 1):

What it refers to is that a inlined subquery can lead to slow queries and a CTE (which operates as an optimization fence avoids that). Here is an example [bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1RfAwz-0006Us-7B@wrigleys.postgresql.org) for this.